# jCrop: Handle different image sizes

Tags: jquery, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, jcrop

Quite some time ago I used jCrop in a Bootstrap-Modal to be able to crop an image before uploading it. Everything worked fine, but recently I had a little different task.

The task was to create a Dropzone where the user can drop as many image files as he wants. The Files should be displayed in ein Image-Tage in another modal. Everything works fine until here.

So lets assume that the user drops 5 image files. The structure would look something like this.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="CropContainer1">
        <img class="ImgCropObject" src="data:image/jpeg....">
    </div>
    <div class="CropContainer2">
        <img class="ImgCropObject" src="data:image/jpeg....">
    </div>
    <div class="CropContainer3">
        <img class="ImgCropObject" src="data:image/jpeg....">
    </div>
    <div class="CropContainer4">
        <img class="ImgCropObject" src="data:image/jpeg....">
    </div>
    <div class="CropContainer5">
        <img class="ImgCropObject" src="data:image/jpeg....">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the first image will be initialized with jCrop using the following code.

```
$('.CropContainer' + (ElemNow)).find(".ImgCropObject").Jcrop({
        boxWidth: 570,
        boxHeight: 450,
        aspectRatio: 16/9,
        setSelect: [0,0,300,300],
        bgOpacity: .4,
        minSize: [300,300],
        onSelect: function(){
            CropSelectorSet = true;
        },
        onRelease: function(){
            CropSelectorSet = false;
        }
    }, function(){
        CropAPI = this;
    });
```

This also works pretty fine. The user can cut the image, it is sent to the server. Right after the upload, the "CropAPI" gets CropAPI.destroy()'ed. Now the next container (2) will be displayed and the above code will be applied again. This also works fine, until the end.

BUT: If there are 2 differnt image sizes, image resolutions or something like that, jCrop returns wrong coordinates to crop - I tried my best but can't figure out where the problem exactly is. Also tried different solutions with "trueSize" (jCrop Documentation), but nothing helped.

Really hope someone can help me. Thanks very much in advance!

You can find a minimal example here: [Example](http://www.manuelmaurer.at/tryit.php)

Using the following code in your Browser console you can show the coords of the crop-area:

```
console.log("X: " + CropAPI.tellSelect()["x"] + "\n Y: " + CropAPI.tellSelect()["y"] + "\n H: " + CropAPI.tellSelect()["h"] + "\n W: " + CropAPI.tellSelect()["w"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, after 2 ***** days, I finally found the problem -> $.each does not put the images there one after another in the same order they have in the FILES-Array from the dropzone... So when I cut an image, the coordinates are actually correct, BUT what I didn't know is that actually the wrong image is being uploaded and cut. So the result was really weird and it's a shame I didn't find this solution earlier.